# How to fully remove the eclipse package?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, eclipse

I installed Eclipse via command `apt-get install eclipse`.

This command completed correctly.

After this, I run Eclipse and add some configurations: Added a new URL for "Available Software Sites".

On the next step, I try removed Eclipse via `apt-get remove eclipse` and install eclipse again.

And here I see a surprise: in the newly installed Eclipse, I see my old URL for "Available Software Sites".

So, I guess, that the configuration file(s) is not removed.

After this I tried different commands: something like this:

```
sudo dpkg -r eclipse
sudo apt-get --purge remove eclipse
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But after I again install Eclipse I see my URL.

How I can fully remove Eclipse along with its configuration files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your personal configuration files are stored in your home directory.

Check `~/.eclipse/` or `~/.config/eclipse/`

Note, these are hidden directories (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Nautilus to show, or `ls -la`).

Comment: Thanks. But, how to remove eclipse from here too?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of old configurations and options, delete the .eclipse directory from your home directory. You can do this with the help of following command:

```
rm -rf ~/.eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty normal behaviour because in this case all the settings belong to a personal profile and not to the application itself; also at the first boot you were asked for the workspace location and there you can locate your files, and that path is used by Eclipse to retrieve your settings.